# Pitch detection results wrong

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, pitch-tracking

I am using `freq_from_crossings` from [here](https://github.com/endolith/waveform-analyzer/blob/master/frequency_estimator.py#L20) (I haven't changed the code). My input is an [audio file](https://ufile.io/gaqdo) with an acoustic guitar E2 note and nothing else (as my microphone is pretty bad, the sound is not very clear).

This is the waveform:

[image: waveform]
And this is the spectrogram I am getting:

[image: spectrogram]

From the spectrogram it is pretty clear that the loudest harmonic corresponds to the E2 note. However, `freq_from_crossings` returns 415.461966359 which is not at all the pitch played. What components could have gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A waveform that is not a single pure sinewave can have more zero crossings than once per pitch period.  Within one period, it can include lots of "wiggles" that cross zero.  The harmonic content of your guitar note spectrogram shows that the total waveform is far from being a single pure sinewave.  It's also changing over time.

Therefore, estimating pitch frequency from zero crossings won't work for these types of guitar sounds.

Comment: I see. Do you think that `freq_from_fft` would be better?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, zero-crossings and auto-correlation are terrible ways to attempt pitch detection -- even on a monophonic signal. Consider using a method that employs either a FFT or DFT transform to acquire the initial frequency activity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(music)#Pitch_detection

https://github.com/CreativeDetectors/PitchScope_Player